# Do CSS animations continue to run in background when display is set to none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a loader animation using css when I am loading something via AJAX for a search menu. I want to know if the animation would continue to run in the background when I set display to be "none" using JavaScript.

Comment: @BenM they don't: *Setting the display property to none will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants. If an element has a display of none, updating display to a value other than none will start all animations applied to the element by the animation-name property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with display other than none.* https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animations

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, always believed they did!